# iText 7 - Dynamic Header

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm using iText 7 to create a PDF document, with a rather complex header.

This header will show a complex table on the first page and a different table on the remaining pages. This table will contain different information that is passed in and will contain the page number and total number of pages.

I know how to create a header with a table.
I know how to create Page X of Y.

I do not know how to create different headers (different tables with different height) that change on some logic when using iText 7:

If page 1 use Table A, if page > 1 use Table B.

Is there some way to solve this with iText 7? Any help would be appreciated.

Btw:
In iText 5 i solved this and have no problem doing this, but I want to use the latest version of iText (7).

Comment: I don't understand how you can possibly *not know how to create different headers with page X of Y that change on some logic in iText 7, like page number,* if you do *know how to create a header with a table* and *how to create Page X of Y.* Thus, you should make clear where your exact problems are, e.g. by showing a code sample which illustrates where you got stuck.

Comment: The text was a bit misleading, my fault. Changed some of it. Code would nice, I'll see if I can fine some example. However, what I found so far is that in iText 7 you are using page top margin to set space for the header, and from what I know so far is that this margin is fixed and equal on all pages.

Comment: You can change the margins to use for the next page using `Document.setMargins`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. And I changed from using END_PAGE to START_PAGE event.

Comment: As a side note. I see that when I use both START_PAGE and END_PAGE events and there are more than one page, e.g. three pages, the events are not synchronized. The order are like this: START_PAGE 1, START_PAGE 2, END_PAGE 1, START_PAGE 3, END_PAGE 2, END_PAGE 3, the number is the page number.

Comment: It looks like the next page is started before the previous one is finally closed. Can be quite a pain if one does not know that and tries to construct interesting event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement IEventHandler and add it as an event listener for adding new page
simple example :

```
public class PdfEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        int pageNum = pdfDoc.getPageNumber(page)
                if(pageNum> 1 )
                    //add table1
                else 
                    //add Table 2
 }
}
```

and then add this event handler to you document event listener like this

```
 PdfEventHandler handler = new PdfEventHandler();

 pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, handler);
```